# Saving and Loading CNN model

Tags: testing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, prediction

I have a CNN model and I want to save it and load it for prediction in different tab. But I am confused whether the model.evulotion part is included in the part I will save. And I don't know if it would be better to use Model.checkpoint or model.save to save and load. Is there anyone have an idea ? Thank you in advance

I'm in dilemma about using both of them so I've use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `model.eval()` just tells the PyTorch model to use mean values for batch normalisation, and deactivates the dropout layers. You can save your model without using `model.eval()` as it will not affect the performance.
While saving model, saving model's state dictionary is preferred. This can be done as shown:

```py
#declare class of model here
model = NeuralNetwork()
#add training code below
...
#saving model, the model will be saved at the intermediateWeightPath location
intermediateWeightPath = "./bestmodel.pth"
torch.save(model.state_dict(), intermediateWeightPath)
```

Comment: Oh I mean “ When I Need to save my model, before or after using test data (sorry for my bad English ) and My teacher Said pickle module can be used for saving. But pickle is for ML models not DL models as I know

Comment: Yeah you do not need to use ```model.eval()``` before saving your model. As for the pickle file, usually use the inbuilt model saving functions, rather than saving a model as a pickle file.

Comment: Thank u so much I'm grateful for answering my questions